# How does the call stack look like for a recursive delete call in a binary search tree?

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree, delete-operator

I'm working through a Binary Search Tree tutorial. And I find this function `destroy_tree(node* leaf)`. Its behaviour worries me - I can't imagine how the call stack looks like, can you explain it to me?

```
void btree::destroy_tree(node* leaf)
{
    if (leaf !=NULL)
    {
        destroy_tree(leaf->left);
        destroy_tree(leaf->right);
        delete leaf;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For questions about recursive functions, sometimes it helps to just think of or draw a simple tree and just map out on paper how the function goes through it.

First thing, it's been a while since I used c++, but for the sake of this example I'm going to change your code to:

```
void btree::destroy_tree(node* leaf)
{
    if(leaf !=NULL)
    {
        if (leaf->left != NULL)
            destroy_tree(leaf->left);

        if (leaf->right != NULL)
            destroy_tree(leaf->right);

        delete leaf;
    }
}
```

just so there's less stuff on the stack.

Think about how the logic of this function works recursively through a tree. Take the following tree example which I snagged from Wikipedia

[image: binary search tree example]
Let's say you call `destroy_tree(root)`. The function `destroy_tree(root)` calls `destroy_tree(node->left)` first, then `destroy_tree(node->right)`. This means that left children are always iterated through before ANY right child is. So to use the numbers in the above tree, the tree would traverse in the order: `8,3,1,6,4,7,10,14,13`. You can see based on this that all left children are traversed. No right child will be traversed while there is still an untraversed left.

The call stack should look similar as the program runs. Calling `destroy_tree(left)` will call ``destroy_tree()` on *every* consecutive left node before any right nodes are reached.